# project working in tomcat but not working from eclipse. error :cant find log4j.properties

Tags: eclipse, struct, log4j

I have a struts project which, I have imported to eclipse from a war file. 
This is working perfectly by deploying it in tomcat. But the same after importing is showing up the error :

```
log4j:ERROR Could not read configuration file from URL [file:/D:/xxxfolder/xxxworkspace/xxxproject/WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties].
java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:xxx\xxx\xxx\WebContent\WEB-INF\classes\log4j.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

I have the log4j.property in src folder.

Please help with proper solution to get rid of it !

Let me know if needed more info

EDIT! 
 I got the root of problem but cant find the solution 
Bu default the ouput build path for src in eclipse is :build/classess. but the tomcat is searching the file at webContent/web_inf/ Classess/ Can you suggest how to do it . how to change the output file of only log4j to the specific it is tomcat is searching in.

Comment: The path is incorrect, which leads to File Not Found. Double check the path.

Comment: Sory i did not get you clearly. Do you mean the location of loj4j is wrong. i hold it under src. I replaced the original path in Question by xxx .

Comment: it said `File Not Found`. Can you make sure the path exists & have proper permission?

Comment: In eclipse project src deployed is under WEBContent --> WEB_INF -->clasess. and mt log4j.properties is present in root of src so , obviously it must be their in that specific path.

Comment: hi shivan your right the file is not in the position it is looking . Bu default the ouput build path for src  in eclipse is :build/classess. but the tomcat is searching the file at webContent/web_inf/ Classess/  Can you suggest how to do it . how to change the output file of only log4j to the specific it is searching .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments above, the conclusion is that, the path is incorrect. After modifying the path, the issue is resolved.